# Why didn't R and Julie just drive away?

Tags: plot-explanation, warm-bodies

In the film, Warm Bodies, R tells Julie that she must wait a few days until the zombies *forget* that she is around before trying to escape. I understand that R is crushing on Julie at this point and would like very much for her to stay. I also understand that he is really trying to keep her safe.

However, when they first sneak out and begin driving the car around the airport for *something to do* *out of boredom*... why do they not just haul ass right then and there? I mean, they were able to get to the car unharmed, it would have been the prime opportunity to just take off. Instead, she ends up sticking around for a few more days. She obviously didn't have to stay.

Comment: It's a Zombie-comedy film and doesn't make sense all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The film was released as something you would want to watch on Valentine's Day. A romance. To give the characters the right state of mind would be to lose some of that romantic essence.

Alternatively, I could try saying something relevant to the point, such as, 'there were a lot of zombies around' or 'the car was low on fuel' or 'she began to enjoy this new zombie and temporarily forgot her situation', but I doubt any of those are the reason.